# c# changing the colour of a button slowly when you move your mouse over it

Tags: c#, colors, mousemove

So i tried to make a button more animated by making that when i hover my mouse over the button its back colour goes slowly from a darker gray to lighter gray, sadly the the `MouseHover` didn't worked out great for me because i had to use it with `if` (`while`, `do` and `for` isn't working at all) so i changed it to `MouseMove` And well that created its own problems, right now the colour getting lighter only when i move my mouse on it, here is the code:

```
    private void BtnPlay_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        byte coloDat = btnPlay.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor.B;

        if (btnPlay.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor != Color.FromArgb(68, 68, 68))
        {
            coloDat++;
            btnPlay.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = Color.FromArgb(coloDat, coloDat, coloDat);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
        }
    }
```

Im gonna use the code multiple times in the project so is there a way to do this without making a wall of text?

Edit: For avoiding confusion; im trying to do my project with `Button.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor` and not `Button.BackgroundColour`.

Comment: Is there any way you could use WPF instead of windows forms?

Comment: I don't think so since i don't know WPF however if there is a way i can make the button in WPF and send that to the WF without so much pain i may try that.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create this in WPF, just create a style with a storyboard. In windows forms, you need to use a timer.

The reason a loop didn't work for you is that the loop was running on the same thread as the UI, so the UI wasn't being updated until after your loop was over. To animate an effect in windows forms, you have to let the event function end so that the UI can update and then have your function called again for the next frame. That is what the timer element does.

I created a demo program with two animated buttons. To create buttons with animated background colors I first set up a start color, end color, the amount I want the color to change in each frame, the button the mouse is currently over and the transition progress of each button. I added that last so that I could have the buttons gradually transition back after the mouse was over something else.

```
    private Color startColor = Color.AliceBlue;
    private Color endColor = Color.BlueViolet;
    private double step = 0.01;
    private Button lastOver = null;
    private Dictionary<Button, double> transitionProgress = new Dictionary<Button, double>();
```

Then I attached the event handlers of both of my buttons to the same functions, the functions below. The first uses ContainsKey so that I can make more buttons animated by just assigning them to these event handler functions.

```
    private void demoButton_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender != lastOver)
        {
            lastOver = (Button)sender;
            if (!transitionProgress.ContainsKey(lastOver))
            {
                transitionProgress[lastOver] = 0.0;
            }
        }
    }

    private void demoButton_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lastOver = null;
    }
```

Then I created a Timer with the following event handler. It goes through each button and transitions it based on whether the mouse is currently over that button. It also only updates the background color if it has changed to improve performance.

```
    private void styleUpdate_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < transitionProgress.Count; i++)
        {
            Button button = transitionProgress.Keys.ElementAt(i);
            bool changing = false;
            if (button == lastOver)
            {
                if (transitionProgress[button] < 1.0)
                {
                    transitionProgress[button] = Math.Min(1.0, transitionProgress[button] + step);
                    changing = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (transitionProgress[button] > 0.0)
                {
                    transitionProgress[button] = Math.Max(0.0, transitionProgress[button] - step);
                    changing = true;
                }
            }
            if (changing)
            {
                double progress = transitionProgress[button];
                button.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(
                    (int)Math.Floor((endColor.R - startColor.R) * progress + startColor.R),
                    (int)Math.Floor((endColor.G - startColor.G) * progress + startColor.G),
                    (int)Math.Floor((endColor.B - startColor.B) * progress + startColor.B)
                    );
            }
        }
    }
```

The timer has to be enabled and the interval set to 16

```
        this.styleUpdate.Enabled = true;
        this.styleUpdate.Interval = 16;
        this.styleUpdate.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.styleUpdate_Tick);
```

That does seem like a lot of code, but to add it to another button, you just need two more lines of code.

```
        this.yourButtonName.MouseLeave += new System.EventHandler(this.demoButton_MouseLeave);
        this.yourButtonName.MouseHover += new System.EventHandler(this.demoButton_MouseHover);
```

Comment: This is brilliant! However it seems its only working on system style buttons. For changing it to flat i tried to change the `button.BackColor` part with `button.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor` however it didn't do anything also im trying to sneak `button.FlatAppearance.BorderColor` into the code as a different colour value but nothing working so far. Exactly where should i put that in?
Also i only need one but for the people who may have a question about this in the feature what should we do if we want to have more than one colour change value?

Comment: I tried setting the FlatStyle property of one of the buttons to Flat and the existing code worked unmodified, as long as the FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor was not set to anything. I also tried modifying the code to animate the FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor property, and that kind of worked except that it no longer fades out.

Comment: Ah my bad, even though you clearly said "Then I created a Timer with the following event handler." i created mine with designer as well and there was two timers with the same name because of that. Im gonna tinker around with the flat appearance for some time, i'll tell you if i could find anything. Thank you!